# Functional reposiotory - build get() based on find()/create() methods

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have algebra like this

```
object Algebra {
  case class Product(id: String, description: String)
  case class ShoppingCart(id: String, products: List[Product])

  trait ShoppingCarts[F[_]] {
    def create(id: String): F[Unit]
    def get(id: String): F[ShoppingCart]
    def find(id: String): F[Option[ShoppingCart]]
  }
}
```

I came up with following implementation. But I wonder if it would be possible to implement it as generic method within the trait itself. I have tried to bound context to functor to gain access to map but this is not valid construct.

```
override def get(id: String): ScRepoState[ShoppingCart] =
  find(id).flatMap {
    case Some(sc) => sc.pure[ScRepoState]
    case None => create(id) *> get(id)
  }
```

Another problem is to implement addMany() metdhod. I got something like this

```
def addMany[F[_] : Monad](cartId: String, products: List[Product])(implicit shoppingCarts: ShoppingCarts[F]): F[ShoppingCart] = {
    for {
      cart    <- shoppingCarts.get(cartId)
      product <- products.pure[F]
      newCart <- product.traverse(product => shoppingCarts.add(cart, product))
    } yield newCart
  }
```

I struggle how to mix differetnt wrappers within single for comprehension block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I wonder if it would be possible to implement it as generic method within the trait itself.

Not quite. Scala 2 doesn't allow traits to have parameters, but you can use an abstract class instead. You can either not use trait entirely, or have a default class with all derivable implementations, e.g.:

```scala
abstract class DefaultShoppingCarts[F[_]: Monad] extends ShoppingCarts[F] {
  override def get(id: String): F[ShoppingCart] =
    find(id).flatMap {
      case Some(sc) => sc.pure[F]
      case None     => create(id) >> get(id)
    }
}
```

This is my preferred method, but there are other options for changing traits directly.

---

You can add a `Monad` parameter to a method:

```scala
trait ShoppingCarts[F[_]] {
  def create(id: String): F[Unit]
  def find(id: String): F[Option[ShoppingCart]]
  def get(id: String)(implicit F: Monad[F]): F[ShoppingCart] =
    find(id).flatMap {
      case Some(sc) => sc.pure[F]
      case None     => create(id) >> get(id)
    }
}
```

This is quite different from what we did in abstract class example, b/c the *use site* of `ShoppingCarts` will be forced to have a monad available instead of *construction site*, and the implementor, if they want to override the method, would have to replicate the signature exactly even if that `Monad[F]` is not used.

---

You can also emulate what trait parameters would do with abstract implicit defs:

```scala
  trait ShoppingCarts[F[_]] {
    implicit protected def F: Monad[F]
    def create(id: String): F[Unit]
    def get(id: String): F[ShoppingCart] =
      find(id).flatMap {
        case Some(sc) => sc.pure[F]
        case None     => create(id) >> get(id)
      }
    def find(id: String): F[Option[ShoppingCart]]
  }
```

This works but you are more likely to run into technical issues with implicit scope when implementing the `F` member.

---

> I struggle how to mix different wrappers within single for comprehension block

You don't. No mixing is allowed. Don't use for-comprehension for list, only use it for `F`. In some more complex cases you might want to nest for comprehensions, or use a monad transformer, but here you only need to work in F. I'm also not sure what's the return type of `add`, but assuming it's `F[ShoppingCart]`:

```scala
def addMany[F[_] : Monad](cartId: String, products: List[Product])(implicit shoppingCarts: ShoppingCarts[F]): F[ShoppingCart] = {
    for {
      cart    <- shoppingCarts.get(cartId)
      results <- products.traverse(product => shoppingCarts.add(cart, product))
      // results is a list of intermediate carts, get the last one; fallback if list was empty
    } yield results.lastOption.getOrElse(cart)
  }
```

Also please ask second question separately next time.